# Why LuxiMono's dashes disappear when copying-pasting from Acrobat Reader?

Tags: fonts, punctuation, copy-paste, acrobat

Consider the following MCE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{luximono}
\begin{document}
\texttt{foo-bar}
\end{document}
```

When copying-pasting "foo-bar" from Acrobat Reader, the dash disappears: one obtains "foobar".

AFAICS, this trouble doesn't arise:

- with PDF viewers other than Acrobat Reader,
- or with fonts other than LuxiMono.

Do you know why and how to get the expected behavior?

Comment: Confirmed on my Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map the glyph name to the correct unicode position:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{luximono}
\pdfglyphtounicode{hyphen}{002D}

\pdfgentounicode=1
\begin{document}
\texttt{foo-bar} 
\end{document}
```

<s>(I don't know why adobe doesn't copy it, when the name is hyphen, perhaps it tries to be too clever and removes hyphenation dashes).</s>

I unpacked the vf and followed the way of the hyphen:

In `ul9r8t.vpl` contains (shortened)

```
(CHARACTER O 55
   ...
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR O 255)
      )
   )
```

This means that the hyphen (dec 45=octal 55) is mapped to octal 255=dec 173.
This is also what one gets in the pdf: `(foo\255bar)`  and not `(foo-bar)`.

8r.enc encodes `/hyphen` twice: once at position 45, and once at 173.

The luximono font (in `ul9r8a.afm`) has `hyphen` at position 45, and `sfthyphen` ("soft hyphen") at position 173.

So imho adobe is doing the right thing, a `sfthyphen` should disappear at copy&paste and the fault is faulty: A typewriter which even sets \hyphenchar to -1 shouldn't remap the hyphen like this.

Comment: Is it worth reporting to the LuxiMono font pack's maintainer (well, the last update dates from 2004-01-26)?

Comment: I added some remarks regarding the source of the problem, but I have no idea if there is anyone who could correct it.

Comment: The strange thing is that the other PDF viewers have the expected behavior. I reported to the maintainer.

Comment: Well at first, a pdf viewer needs to be clever enough to suppress a soft hyphen and at second the encoding file (8r.enc) uses /hyphen as name, so the situation is a bit messy.