# Time New Roman - hyphens are not visible when copied from PDF (xelatex issue?)

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, times

A similar problem to this [Why LuxiMono's dashes disappear when copying-pasting from Acrobat Reader?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369596/why-luximonos-dashes-disappear-when-copying-pasting-from-acrobat-reader)

The solution from that post does not work for me:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \pdfglyphtounicode 

l.9 \pdfglyphtounicode
```

Hyphens used to work, but something recently changed and when copying hyphenated words from PDF it copies it as an invisible character.

The problem is for Times New Roman, using the default font work fine.

Is there a way to force LaTeX to use the "-" character for hyphenated words?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext,12pt]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\title{x}
\author{x}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

not-copy-able-hyphens

\printbibliography[category=cited]

\end{document}
```

using

```
latexmk -pdf -xelatex
```

**EDIT, thanks to @ArTourter:**
Compling with *lualatex* works fine (I need xelatex in my full example).

**EDIT, following on the idea from @ulrike-fischer, checking the fonts in the correct (lualatex) and buggy (xelatex) PDF. Lualatex seems to be using the font from /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Times New Roman.ttf, but the fonts seem to be the same across the two PDFs**

```
lualatex
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
XXWCFY+TimesNewRomanPSMT             CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     19  0
DQUQJG+TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT      CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     27  0
```

```
xelatex
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
JXZBTE+TimesNewRomanPSMT             CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      6  0
PVHPPI+TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT      CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     13  0
```

creates:

[image: PDF output]

Which then copy-pastes to a text editor (bottom) and LibreOffice (top) like this:

[image]

The character seems to be there but it's using something weird rather than a hyphen.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with xelatex, as if complied with lualatex the hyphens are present after copy-paste.

Comment: xetex is probably finding the wrong font. Try with `\setmainfont{times.ttf}` (or whatever real font lualatex is using, check at the end of the log-file)

Comment: Try `\XeTeXgenerateactualtext=1`.
However in a test here, a chosen region seems to be
shown incorrectly (a bug in Acrobat?).

Comment: xetex maps the hyphen to the soft hyphen U+00AD in the ToUnicode settings. lualatex (also with the harfbuzz render) maps it to U+002D. The problem is probably that times (and also arial which has the same problem) don't have glyph names.

Comment: @Ulrike, thanks that's really insightful. What might be the solution and why was it working well before?

Comment: @Adam: I reported the problem to the author of [x]dvipdfmx.
Sources for ToUnicode were a bit changed so we are seeing
different behaviors. He is considering a better solution.
Lets wait for the solution.